# Convert Hierarchical List into Datatable/dataSet

Tags: c#, json.net, strongly-typed-dataset

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "query": {
    "count": 43,
    "created": "2016-03-12T09:46:36Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "results": {
      "a": [
        {
          "class": "image",
          "href": "/wiki/File:Yahoo!_logo.svg",
          "img": {
            "alt": "Yahoo! logo.svg",
            "data-file-height": "233",
            "data-file-width": "1000",
            "height": "51",
            "src": "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/
                    Yahoo%21_logo.svg/220px-Yahoo%21_logo.svg.png",
            "srcset": "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/
                       Yahoo%21_logo.svg/330px-Yahoo%21_logo.svg.png 1.5x
                      , //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/
                      Yahoo%21_logo.svg/440px-Yahoo%21_logo.svg.png 2x",
            "width": "220"
          }
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Types_of_business_entity",
          "title": "Types of business entity",
          "content": "Type"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Public_company",
          "title": "Public company",
          "content": "Public"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Ticker_symbol",
          "title": "Ticker symbol",
          "content": "Traded as"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/NASDAQ",
          "title": "NASDAQ",
          "content": "NASDAQ"
        },
        {
          "class": "external text",
          "href": "http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/yhoo",
          "rel": "nofollow",
          "content": "YHOO"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/NASDAQ-100",
          "title": "NASDAQ-100",
          "content": "NASDAQ-100 Component"
        },
        {
          "class": "mw-redirect",
          "href": "/wiki/S%26P_500",
          "title": "S&P 500",
          "content": "S&P 500 Component"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Sunnyvale,_California",
          "title": "Sunnyvale, California",
          "content": "Sunnyvale"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Entrepreneurship",
          "title": "Entrepreneurship",
          "content": "Founder(s)"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Jerry_Yang_(entrepreneur)",
          "title": "Jerry Yang (entrepreneur)",
          "content": "Jerry Yang"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/David_Filo",
          "title": "David Filo",
          "content": "David Filo"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Maynard_Webb",
          "title": "Maynard Webb",
          "content": "Maynard Webb"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Marissa_Mayer",
          "title": "Marissa Mayer",
          "content": "Marissa Mayer"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/David_Filo",
          "title": "David Filo",
          "content": "David Filo"
        },
        {
          "href": "#cite_note-1",
          "span": [
            "[",
            "]"
          ],
          "content": "1"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Product_(business)",
          "title": "Product (business)",
          "content": "Products"
        },
        {
          "class": "mw-redirect",
          "href": "/wiki/Yahoo_News",
          "title": "Yahoo News",
          "content": "Yahoo News"
        },
        {
          "class": "mw-redirect",
          "href": "/wiki/Yahoo_Mail",
          "title": "Yahoo Mail",
          "content": "Yahoo Mail"
        },
        {
          "class": "mw-redirect",
          "href": "/wiki/Yahoo_Finance",
          "title": "Yahoo Finance",
          "content": "Yahoo Finance"
        },
        {
          "class": "mw-redirect",
          "href": "/wiki/Yahoo_Sports",
          "title": "Yahoo Sports",
          "content": "Yahoo Sports"
        },
        {
          "class": "mw-redirect",
          "href": "/wiki/Yahoo_Search",
          "title": "Yahoo Search",
          "content": "Yahoo Search"
        },
        {
          "class": "mw-redirect",
          "href": "/wiki/Yahoo_Messenger",
          "title": "Yahoo Messenger",
          "content": "Yahoo Messenger"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers",
          "title": "Yahoo! Answers",
          "content": "Yahoo! Answers"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Tumblr",
          "title": "Tumblr",
          "content": "Tumblr"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Flickr",
          "title": "Flickr",
          "content": "Flickr"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/List_of_Yahoo!-owned_sites_and_services",
          "title": "List of Yahoo!-owned sites and services",
          "content": "See Yahoo products"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Revenue",
          "title": "Revenue",
          "content": "Revenue"
        },
        {
          "href": "#cite_note-2",
          "span": [
            "[",
            "]"
          ],
          "content": "2"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Earnings_before_interest_and_taxes",
          "title": "Earnings before interest and taxes",
          "content": "Operating income"
        },
        {
          "href": "#cite_note-10K-3",
          "span": [
            "[",
            "]"
          ],
          "content": "3"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Net_income",
          "title": "Net income",
          "content": "Net income"
        },
        {
          "href": "#cite_note-4",
          "span": [
            "[",
            "]"
          ],
          "content": "4"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Asset",
          "title": "Asset",
          "content": "Total assets"
        },
        {
          "href": "#cite_note-5",
          "span": [
            "[",
            "]"
          ],
          "content": "5"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Equity_(finance)",
          "title": "Equity (finance)",
          "content": "Total equity"
        },
        {
          "href": "#cite_note-6",
          "span": [
            "[",
            "]"
          ],
          "content": "6"
        },
        {
          "href": "#cite_note-7",
          "span": [
            "[",
            "]"
          ],
          "content": "7"
        },
        {
          "class": "mw-redirect",
          "href": "/wiki/List_of_acquisitions_by_Yahoo!",
          "title": "List of acquisitions by Yahoo!",
          "content": "Yahoo subsidiaries"
        },
        {
          "class": "external text",
          "href": "https://www.yahoo.com",
          "rel": "nofollow",
          "wbr": [
            null,
            null
          ],
          "content": "www.yahoo.com"
        },
        {
          "href": "/wiki/Alexa_Internet",
          "title": "Alexa Internet",
          "content": "Alexa"
        },
        {
          "class": "external text",
          "href": "//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Yahoo!&action=edit",
          "content": "[update]"
        },
        {
          "href": "#cite_note-alexaranking-8",
          "span": [
            "[",
            "]"
          ],
          "content": "8"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

...but I am unable to convert this into `DataTable` in `.Net`

I need to convert the response into `DataSet`.

following are my classes that i used while converting response.i know we easily convert the response in list but the problem arise when we convert the response into datatable or dataset any one who have any solution? i have tried to convert this into datatable

```
public class YahooImg
{
    public string alt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data-file-height")]
    public string data_file_height { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data-file-width")]
    public string data_file_width { get; set; }
    public string height { get; set; }
    public string src { get; set; }
    public string srcset { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
}
public class YahooData
{
    [JsonProperty("class")]
    public string CLASS { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Img")]
    public YahooImg img { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public List<string> span { get; set; }
    public List<object> wbr { get; set; }
}
public class YahooResults
{
    [JsonProperty("A")]
    public List<YahooData> a { get; set; }
}
public class YahooQuery
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Results")]
    public YahooResults results { get; set; }
}
public class YahooAPIData
{
    [JsonProperty("query")]
    public YahooQuery Yahooquery { get; set; }
    public YahooQuery GetYahooResult(string url)
    {
        var ds = new YahooAPIData();
        if (!url.ToLower().Contains("yahoo"))
            return ds.Yahooquery;
        try
        {
            var wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json");
            var response = wc.DownloadString(url);
           var dss = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YahooAPIData>(response);               
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            var r = exp;
        }
        return ds.Yahooquery;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to external sites unless it is to support content already in your question.

Comment: You really need to remove the `catch (Exception exp)` - it's a bad practice to catch everything like that. Also you need to dispose of the `WebClient`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what exactly you want to do as you have not posted and dataset structure in which you want to parse but, If you create following classes then, I think you can parse your JSON content in Query object model.

```
public class Query
{
    int count;
    datetime created;
    string lang;
    Result[] a; 
}

public class Result
{

    string _class;
    string href;
    Image img;

}

public class Image
{

    string alt;
    string data_file_height;
    string data_file_width;
    string height;
    string src;
    string srcset;
    string width;

}
```

Comment: Can you at least show how to convert the JSON to this object model? P.S. this doesn't even compile at the moment.

Comment: @Trikaldarshi i have the same structure of classes that you mention. i convert the json into list the problem is when i convert the resulted list into data table because list have hierarchical data.

Comment: @Enigmativity: There are several libraries available to convert JSON to object model viz. *Newtonsoft.Json*, Its upto you want you want to use.

Comment: I have tried to do the conversion. I can't make it work. This answer doesn't address the question in its current form.

Comment: Exactly  that is clearly mentioned in very first line of the answer, it only helps to give an C# object model in which this json string can be parsed.

Comment: @Trikaldarshi so you have any solution to convert the resultant list into Dataset or table ? i have try to write the extension method but at certain point it break the code :( .